# Rerunning Flaky Protractor Tests Only

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

On our web application we are using protractor to test real user experiences and while it accurately tests the user flow they can be quite flaky for a multitude of reasons that could be out of our control.  As a result it is hard to rely on the test results because the failures could be noise.

Is there a way to run just the flaky tests?  I've tried to use the protractor-flakes but it doesn't seem to work when running in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are ways to re-run flakey tests, but you will need to use a library/plugin outside of Protractor. It doesn't look like this functionality will be available in Protractor any time soon.

I use an node module called [protractor-errors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-errors). This plugin will record when a test fails and allow you to re-run only failed tests. It supports running sharded tests in parallel. The catch is that it currently only supports tests written in Jasmine.